# Dependency Injection and Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, dependency-injection

I'm having trouble with getting generics and DI to work together in an MVC Core project. I have a generic class (this is just a fragment). I need to initialize Input and Output because of how these are used in other parts of the code, so I'm using Activator to provide initial values and the new() constraint.

```
public class Message<TIn, TOut> : 
    where TIn : class, IMessagePart, new()
    where TOut : class, IMessagePart, new() {

    public Message(){}    
    public Message(TIn inpart, TOut outpart) {
        Input = inpart;
        Output = outpart;
    }

    public TIn Input { get; set; } = (TIn)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TIn));
    public TOut Output { get; set; } = (TOut)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TOut));
}
```

I have other classes that are used by this, and they have some static utility classes. I'm trying to replace these static classes using DI.

```
public class Project : IMessagePart{
    int y = 1; 
    var x = StaticUtilityClass.StaticMethod(y);
}
```

is used like this

```
var projectMessage = new Message<Project, Project>();
```

I'm converting the static utility classes to instance classes and injecting them. I'm using the built-in .Net core container. I converted the utilities to instance classes and registered them as concrete singletons in the container. For most things I can just do the normal-

```
public class SomeClass{
    private readonly UtilityClass _utility;
    public SomeClass(UtilityClass utility){
        _utility = utility;

    var x = _utility.Method(1);
}
```

Things work fine until I get to the generics. I can't do constructor injection on projectMessage, because the generic needs to new it up and it has the new() constraint, so I need a parameterless constructor. If I add just the an injecting constructor I get

> 'Project' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TIn' in the generic type
>   or method 'Message'.

and if I add both constructors Activator is only going to call the one without parameters, so DI isn't invoked. I tried using the overload of CreateInstance a few different ways, but no luck tricking it.

Any suggestions here? I don't know if I should stay with statics, try some sort of service locator approach, or if there is a different way to writing the generic.

Comment: Message seems like runtime data to me. You should not use a DI container to construct runtime data and you [should not](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) inject runtime data into your components. Why are you trying to accomplish this with a DI container?

Comment: Yes, message is runtime. It carries object pairs to Views. The root of the problem is that message is runtime and does not use DI, but the classes inside (e.g., Project) have dependencies that make sense to inject - like data access. They are ModelBound (thus Activator) and need noparam. Message isn't part of the DI hierarchy, the services aren't available to the interior objects. In some ways, DI makes a parameterized constructor appear "unparameterized" - no error. In a more general sense, I'm trying to "skip" a node in the DI hierarchy - above it use DI, below it use DI, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why you are getting the error you're seeing is the `new()` constraints. That specifies that the parameter [must have a public parameterless constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint). Which is exactly what your error says. Removing that constraint should fix that error. However, you still have another issue if you want to use DI.

Aside from `IMessagePart` none of your classes have backing interfaces. In order to use DI effectively you need to define an `IMessage`, `IProject` etc. Then your *container* can create specific instances at runtime, rather than using the Activators like you are now. So your `Message` declaration would look like:

```
public class Message<TIn, TOut> : IMessage,
    where TIn : class, IMessagePart
    where TOut : class, IMessagePart
{
    public TIn input { get; set; }
    public TOut output { get; set; } 

    public Message(TIn inpart, TOut outpart) {
        this.input = inpart;
        this.output = outpart;
    }
}
```

You would setup your DI container something like:

```
public Startup()
{
    var container = new DiContainer(); // I know this is the wrong name; I'm not familiar with the built in container naming and functionality.

    container.Register<IMessage>();
    container.Register<IMessagePart>();
    container.Register<IProject>();

    // Register other stuff here
}
```

Change the syntax there for your specific container. You also have the option of registering your instances something like:

```
container.Register<Message>(() => Message(part1, part2));
```

so that you specifically inject a `Message` that is newed up at Startup time, but that's not really ideal in most cases. Usually you want your DI container to dynamically create an instance as needed (hence the interfaces), rather than using a single concrete instantiation. There are exceptions of course; a SQL connection is one common one.

Comment: there is no need to always use interfaces for everything in DI. The containers will instantiate from classes directly, and it is common to do that - that's what EF does with DataContext. Message is a container that holds a lot of different types that are defined throughout the code. Kind of like List<>. I do have an interface for it, but it's not the type of class you would DI, it's more common to create them and fill them with initializers. There are other reasons not to use them here, because I need typed messages - I would need to create many ifaces with `out` to implement it.

Comment: Yes, I pointed that out in the last part of my answer. You are correct that interfaces are not *required*. But they do make DI and unit testing much, *much* easier. Additionally, your List<> example is a poor one. List<> implements 8 different (though related) interfaces. Without seeing the rest of your codebase I can't be sure, but I doubt you'd need `out` parameters. Your classes could require specific message types (IXMessage vs IYMessage, or both) which could differ in their implementation.

Comment: I know it's hard to help without seeing the whole thing, but thanks. I added some more info in a response above. The more general question is when I have an object that is not created by DI, is there any way to "start" DI for the objects below? In this case, I have utility-type classes I want to inject instead of using as static. They are now DI and use DI services themselves. I can expose the container as a "global" and pick it up in the constructor body of the non-DI class, which "resumes" DI, but it's not very pretty.

Comment: I think that @Steven is correct and `Messages` shouldn't be injected with/as runtime data. I would create them as needed (in run time code, not in the composition root) as lightweight objects which don't contain `Project` objects themselves, but instead have a `ProjectId`. Those ids would then be able to key back to existing `Project`s which were created by your DI container. Whatever is processing those `Message`s can then access an injected `List<Project>` to do whatever it needs to do with the `Message`.

Comment: Thing is, Projects need to be objects. A Message is newed, and gets sent to a View with a populated Project. The View needs the data, not an Id. The View populates the second Project and sends the message to a controller. I then have both the pre and post states available. The Binder tries to hydrate the `Message<Project, Project>`, but because Message is newed (not DI'ed) it doesn't know about a container, and the container can't get to Project. I can't use DI on Project. I'm using a ServiceLocator in the constructor body to expose the container so I can DI inside Project.